# Failing to build docker image

Tags: docker

I am trying to build a docker image that contains an express server. I have installed docker, logged in and I am in the directory of the folder I want to dockerise. I am using Ubuntu 17.10 64 bit.

[image: A screen shot of the results after running the command.]

I am using the command:

> sudo docker build -t [imageName] .

The error I am getting is:

> The command '/bin/sh -c npm install request -g' return a non zero code: 1

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a typo.

It should be `npm install` not `npm insatall`.